# UITableView with MVVM using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mvvm

I'm working on **MVVM architecture** in Swift with `UITableView`. For this, I have created sample table view.

Can any one please suggest whether I am going correct or any other improvements need to do?

The following are the classes for this architecture.

1. **ViewController** - Contains `UITableView`  and its `delegate` and `datasource` methods.

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {
       let PRODUCT_CELL_IDENTIFIER = "ProductCellIdentifier"

       @IBOutlet weak var productTableView: UITableView!

       var productViewModel: ProductViewModel = ProductViewModel()
   }

   //UITableView Delegate Methods
   extension ViewController {
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return productViewModel.numberOfRowsInSection()
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PRODUCT_CELL_IDENTIFIER) as! ProductTableViewCell
           let product = productViewModel.productsArray[indexPath.row]
           cell.productName.text = product.name
           cell.productQuantity.text = "\(product.quantity)"
           return cell
       }
   }
   ```
2. **ProductViewModel:** - This is ViewModel class.

   ```
   class ProductViewModel: NSObject {
       var productsArray = Array<Product>()

       override init() {
           let product1 = Product(name: "Prodcut1", image_url: "", quantity: 2)
           let product2 = Product(name: "Prodcut2", image_url: "", quantity: 3)
           productsArray.append(product1)
           productsArray.append(product2)
       }

       func numberOfRowsInSection() -> Int {
           return productsArray.count
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Product** - This is the model class

   ```
   class Product: NSObject {
       var name: String
       var image_url: String
       var quantity: Int

       init(name: String, image_url: String, quantity: Int) {
           self.name = name
           self.image_url = image_url
           self.quantity = quantity
       }
   }
   ```
4. **ProductTableViewCell** - This is UITableViewCell class

   ```
   class ProductTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
       @IBOutlet weak var productQuantity: UILabel!
       @IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!
       @IBOutlet weak var productImageView: UIImageView!
   }
   ```

Comment: You are thinking to get array of models in View/ViewController which contradicts MVVM concept, View should not access model, It should get everything it wants from view model.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are doing good job, but you can even improve you product model with adding following function to get array of direct models. It is very useful when you have create array from web Api response.

```
class Product : NSObject
    {

        var imgUrl : String!
        var name : String!
        var quantity : Int!

        init(dictionary: [String:Any])
        {
            imgUrl = dictionary["img_url"] as? String
            name = dictionary["name"] as? String
            quantity = dictionary["quantity"] as? Int
        }
        init(name: String, image_url: String, quantity: Int)
        {
        self.name = name
        self.imgUrl = image_url
        self.quantity = quantity
        }
        public class func modelsFromArray(array:[[String:Any]]) -> [Product]
        {
            var models:[Product] = []
            for item in array
            {
                models.append(Product.init(dictionary:item))
            }
            return models
        }
    }
```

With Usage Like

```
let product1 = Product(name: "Prodcut1", image_url: "", quantity: 2) //Normal Case

    let productList:[[String:Any]] =
        [
        ["name":"Jaydeep","img_url":"xyz","quantity":1],
        ["name":"Jaydeep","img_url":"xyz","quantity":2],
        ["name":"Jaydeep","img_url":"xyz","quantity":3],
        ["name":"Jaydeep","img_url":"xyz","quantity":4],
        ["name":"Jaydeep","img_url":"xyz","quantity":5],
        ["name":"Jaydeep","img_url":"xyz","quantity":6]
        ]
    //Assign Direct Dictionary to Get Array Of Models
/* Very useful when productList is dictionary from server response*/
    let productArray:[Product] = Product.modelsFromArray(array: productList)
```

And Also your Cell Class is Improved By

```
class ProductTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var productQuantity: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productImageView: UIImageView!
func setProductData(product:Product)
{
 self.productName.text = product.name
 self.productQuantity.text = "\(product.quantity)"

}

}
```

**Usage:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PRODUCT_CELL_IDENTIFIER) as! ProductTableViewCell
    let product = productViewModel.productsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.setProductData(product:product)
    return cell
  }
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Little bit of confusion in `modelsFromArray` method.

Comment: You are using two arrays. one is while using and other is `Product` model class.

Comment: first array is use to demostrate you, it may be server response than you can directly pass the response to generate array of models. also note i have updated code for your cell class also

Comment: Thanks alot Jaydeep. Its really helpful. I will update my code.

Comment: One more doubt. YOu have used `implicit uwrapped` variable. For example `var quantity : Int!`. If I want to access it from `ViewController` class, the value is `Options(1). AS per my knowledge `Implicit Unwrapped` object cant be force unwrap. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @Dhanunjaya  you can replace the init method by name = (dictionary["name"] as? String ) ?? ""

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149691/discussion-between-dhanunjaya-and-jaydeep-vyas).

Comment: A view should not talk to a model, but to a view model.

Comment: @JaydeepVyas can you explain like Dhanunjaya. Give separate, Inside Model what and all need, Inside View what and all need and inside View-Model what and all need ???

Comment: @JaydeepVyas thanks for your code. Please include "didSelectRowAt" method too. Where do we write the conditional action for didSelectRowAt ?

Answer (score 3):

MVVM in iOS can be easily implemented without using third party dependencies. For data binding, we can use a simple combination of Closure and didSet to avoid third-party dependencies.

```
public final class Observable<Value> {

    private var closure: ((Value) -> ())?

    public var value: Value {
        didSet { closure?(value) }
    }

    public init(_ value: Value) {
        self.value = value
    }

    public func observe(_ closure: @escaping (Value) -> Void) {
        self.closure = closure
        closure(value)
    }
}
```

An example of data binding from ViewController:

```
final class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {

    private func bind(to viewModel: ViewModel) {
        viewModel.items.observe(on: self) { [weak self] items in
            self?.tableViewController?.items = items
            // self?.tableViewController?.items = viewModel.items.value // This would be Momory leak. You can access viewModel only with self?.viewModel
        }
        // Or in one line:
        viewModel.items.observe(on: self) { [weak self] in self?.tableViewController?.items = $0 }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        bind(to: viewModel)
        viewModel.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

protocol ViewModelInput {
    func viewDidLoad()
}

protocol ViewModelOutput {
    var items: Observable<[ItemViewModel]> { get }
}

protocol ViewModel: ViewModelInput, ViewModelOutput {}
final class DefaultViewModel: ViewModel {  
  let items: Observable<[ItemViewModel]> = Observable([])

  // Implmentation details...
}
```

Later it can be replaced with SwiftUI and Combine (when a minimum iOS version of your app is 13)

In this article, there is a more detailed description of MVVM
https://tech.olx.com/clean-architecture-and-mvvm-on-ios-c9d167d9f5b3